# tinymce images_upload_handler causes JS error on Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE on Vue.js (the offline version), I got an issue with the TinyMCE image upload handler.
it shows **handler(...) is undefined** and the console.log is

```
Uncaught TypeError: progress is not a function
    onprogress http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:17915
    post_image_upload_handler http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:17914
    uploadBlobInfo http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:114101
    uploadBlobInfo http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:114070
    uploadBlobs http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:114119
    1 http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:95149
    each$c http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:95131
    map$1 http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:95148
    uploadBlobs http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:114119
    upload http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:114121
    upload http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:114140
    uploadImage http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:54809
    changeFileInput http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:54717
    promise callback*../../../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.js/changeFileInput/< http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:54714
    fold http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:53505
    changeFileInput http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:54696
    changeHandler http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:54740
    initDialog http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:93772
    fireApiEvent http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:93760
    withSpec http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:93765
    each http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:64759
    withSpec http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:93764
    fireApiEvent http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:93759
    assemble http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:67273
    curry http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:64663
    doTriggerHandler http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76666
    fold http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:64691
    doTriggerHandler http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76660
    doTriggerOnUntilStopped http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76684
    triggerOnUntilStopped http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76701
    triggerEvent http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76824
    processEvent http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:67910
    monitorEvent http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:67942
    triggerEvent http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76824
    dispatchWith http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:66852
    emitWith http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:66839
    handleFiles http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:78978
    onSelect http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:78973
    assemble http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:67273
    curry http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:64663
    doTriggerHandler http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76666
    fold http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:64691
    doTriggerHandler http://172.18.8.28:8000/vendor/appu-dashboard/app.js?id=58dee1dbe917fc02abd9ce855d7d1089:76660
app.js:17915:17
```

this is my vue.js component:

```
<template>
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <editor :init="init"/>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
// TinyMCE
import 'tinymce/tinymce'
import 'tinymce/icons/default/icons'
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme'
import 'tinymce/models/dom/model'
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.css'
import contentUiCss from 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.css';

// TinyMCE plugins
// https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/plugins/
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis';
import 'tinymce/plugins/quickbars/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/media/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/directionality/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/link/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/image/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/table/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/code/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/charmap/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/help/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/save/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autosave/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autolink/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/anchor/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/preview/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/template/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin'

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';


export default {
    name: "AppuPostEditComponent",
    components: {
        'editor': Editor
    },
    data() {
        return {
            init: {
                skin: false,
                height: 500,
                menubar: true,
                plugins: [
                    'lists', 'link', 'image', 'table', 'code', 'help', 'wordcount', 'directionality', 'emoticons',
                    'media', 'quickbars', 'charmap', 'save', 'autosave', 'advlist', 'preview', 'autolink', 'anchor',
                    'template', 'insertdatetime', 'fullscreen',
                ],
                font_family_formats: 'Yekan Bakh FaNum=YekanBakhFaNum;Andale Mono=andale mono,times; Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Arial Black=arial black,avant garde; Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino; Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif; Courier New=courier new,courier; Georgia=georgia,palatino; Helvetica=helvetica; Impact=impact,chicago; Symbol=symbol; Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Terminal=terminal,monaco; Times New Roman=times new roman,times; Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva; Verdana=verdana,geneva; Webdings=webdings; Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats',
                content_css: false,
                language_url: '/vendor/appu-dashboard/assets/js/fa.js',
                font_css: '/css/fonts.css',
                language: 'fa',
                images_upload_handler: this.post_image_upload_handler,
                link_default_target: '_blank',
                content_style: contentUiCss.toString(),
                toolbar: [
                    'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | blocks fontfamily fontsizeinput | link image media table',
                    'align lineheight lists advlist numlist bullist | indent outdent ltr rtl anchor | forecolor backcolor | emoticons charmap | code fullscreen preview | copy cut paste',
                    'save autosave restoredraft export print | insertdatetime  | template removeformat tableofcontents'
                ],
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        post_image_upload_handler(blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
            let xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', '/dashboard-api/base/upload-post-photo');

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
            };

            xhr.onload = function () {
                let json;

                if (xhr.status === 403) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status, {remove: true});
                    return;
                }

                if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
                    failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    return;
                }

                json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                    failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                    return;
                }

                success(json.location);
            };

            xhr.onerror = function () {
                failure('Error:' + xhr.status);
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('_token', this.getCsrfToken());
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
            formData.append('name', blobInfo.filename().split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.'));

            xhr.send(formData);
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

and I am using Laravel; the server-side API works correctly and returns the uploaded image URL as JSON.Location

Thanks for your help and time in advance!

Comment: As the error says, `progress is not a function`.  Reading the error call stack, it originates first from an `onprogress` function, which originates from a `post_image_upload_handler` function.  This is the name of your method.  Here then is the line where your problem exists: `xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) { progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100); };`.  Whatever this `progress` variable is you're using here, it's **not** a function.  You don't show how you're calling this method so I can't say what it is, but try debugging and inspect how you're calling it to understand what's gone wrong.

Comment: @yoduh thanks, but the `progress` function is sent to the TinyMCE editor through the init data object, and it runs by the package. also, the code inside the `post_image_upload_handler` function is the same as their docs [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/#exampleusingimages_upload_handler)

Comment: actually, I doubted the way I implemented the js code as a method in the Vuejs component. maybe js confused `this.` in the init data object, where `images_upload_handler: this.post_image_upload_handler` sends the function name to the TinyMCE object?